# Unterschied zwischen „Überheblichkeitsgefühl“ und „Überlegenheitsgefühl“

Tags: synonym

- Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen *Überheblichkeitsgefühl* und *Überlegenheitsgefühl*?
- Zu welchem Wort passt am besten als Antonym das Wort *Minderwertigkeitsgefühl*?

Comment: Das Gegenteil zu *Minderwertigkeitsgefühl* ist *Selbstwertgefühl*. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selbstwert Es passt gleichermaßen gut (oder schlecht) zu *Überheblichkeit* und *Überlegenheit*.

Comment: Überheblichkeit liegt vor, wenn die Überlegenheit nur eingebildet ist.

Comment: @Em1 Während *Selbstwertgefühl* meinem Sprachgefühl nach eher neutral ist, käme evtl. auch die positivere *Selbstsicherheit*  in Betracht.

Comment: Überheblichkeitsgefühl: "Mann, bin ich gut! Oje, langsam werde ich aber arrogant. :(" Überlegenheitsgefühl: "Yes! Fünf zu null, und der Gegner hat mir nichts entgegenzusetzen! :)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Überlegenheit](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%9Cberlegenheit)*:

> Zustand oder Eigenschaft, in einer bestimmten Sache überlegen zu sein

*[Überheblichkeit](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%9Cberheblichkeit)*:

> ungerechtfertigte Selbstüberschätzung

Der deutsche Fußballverein Bayern München ist gegenüber den meisten Gegner *überlegen* (=sie sind besser). Würden sie aber sagen, dass sie Barcelona mit 5-0 vom Platz fegen, dann wären sie *überheblich* (=halten sich für besser als sie sind).

Durch den Zusatz *-gefühl* beziehst du dich auf das Gefühl der Überlegenheit bzw. Überheblichkeit. Genau genommen macht dies aber nur für ersteres Sinn. Ein Gefühl der Überheblichkeit hat man eigentlich nicht.

Keines der beiden Wörter steht wirklich im Verhältnis zu *[Minderwertigskeitsgefühl](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Minderwertigkeitsgef%C3%BChl)*. Wenn, dann am ehesten noch das *Überlegenheitsgefühl* (wie auch die nachfolgende Definition veranschaulicht). Das *Minderwertigskeitsgefühl* ist aber eher das Gegenteil zu *Selbstwertgefühl* und beschreibt das

> Gefühl der Unterlegenheit, geringeren Geltung, des geringeren Wertes, verglichen mit anderen

Entscheidend ist hier, dass du glaubst, dass du weniger wert bist als jemand anderes. Ein Spieler, der nie  vom Trainer aufgestellt wird, könnte also ein *Minderwertigkeitsgefühl* entwickeln. Der Tabellenletzte der Fussballbundesliga würde aber trotz der Überlegenheit von den Bayern sich **nicht** minderwertig, sondern nur unterlegen fühlen.